# php display variable nummer that constantly changes

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I store the data in a MYSQL database which contains 1 string stored in a table named "data" that looks like the following:

```
parameter.troops.barracks1.3.type_index=x
```

Now I need to echo the value of x which can be anything so how do I do this in PHP?

My guess would be that first I have to check if the string exists or not then if it does it would grab what X is and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everything is in a string I suggest:

```
$string = 'parameter.troops.barracks1.3.type_index=x';
$val = substr($string, strrpos($string, '=')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
$result = trim(strchr($string, '='), '=');
```

This will covert periods `.` to underscores `_` in the name:

```
parse_str($string, $result);
print_r($result);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [parameter_troops_barracks1_3_type_index] => x
)
```

So you can do one of the following:

```
echo $result['[parameter_troops_barracks1_3_type_index'];
//or
echo current($result);
```